# how to create a volume in docker with filesystem?

Tags: curl, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Does Docker supports creating volume with specific filesystem ? I can't find any API call for it, but I can see some document which says it can.

I am trying this with a curl command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d'{
  "name":"visadfasfas","scope":"local","driver":local,"type":"tmpfs"
}' https://<HOST-IP>:2376/volumes/create
```

So it creates the volume but I can't see what type of volume it is in response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes we can create a volume with the specific file system in docker.but they didn't expose the json in any of the document.

i saw the following hint in the doc and tried creating the json.

```
DriverOpts - A mapping of driver options and values. These options are passed directly to the driver and are driver
```

Here is the working json for it :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d'{
  "Name": "vish-test-btrfs",
"DriverOpts":{
"type":"<<<file-system-type>>>"
},
  "Scope": "local"
}' https://<<<HOST_IP>>>>:2376/volumes/create

<<<file-system-type>>> : can be btrfs, aufs etc ..
```

we can't see the type of file system in response, the way to verify is

```
$ : cd <mount point of the volume>

eg :

$: cd /var/lib/docker/volumes/<<volume-Name>>/_data

come one directory back  

$ : cd ..
```

you can see the .json file here where we can see the filesystem type.

```
$: cat <filename.json>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks documentation has listed the types [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/)

```
+---------------+---------------------+
|  Technology   | Storage driver name |
+---------------+---------------------+
| OverlayFS     | overlay or overlay2 |
| AUFS          | aufs                |
| Btrfs         | btrfs               |
| Device Mapper | devicemapper        |
| VFS           | vfs                 |
| ZFS           | zfs                 |
+---------------+---------------------+
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: thanks Rao i went through this document, my question is i want to create a volume with specific FS. eg : aufs. how to create it ?

Comment: This documentation is for graph drivers, not volumes. You can use volume plugins to store the volume data in different systems, but otherwise the volume uses whatever filesystem is on the host.